# Android two-way databinding for methods with parameters

Tags: android, android-databinding, inverse, two-way, two-way-binding

Setter and getter methods of the model have one parameter, like this:

```
public int getPrice(Object key) {
}

public void setPrice(Object key, int price) {
}
```

XML looks like this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edtPrice"
style="@style/CreateShipperItemValueEditTextView"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:hint="@string/hint_price"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLines="1"
android:text="@={shipper.getPrice(priceKey)}"/>
```

**android:text="@={shipper.getPrice(priceKey)}"**

Compiler errors during the building say that we should you use @InverseMethod annotation. 
I try something like this:

```
@InverseMethod(value = "getPrice")
@Override
public void setPrice(Object key, int price) {
    super.setPrice(key, price);
}
```

But in this case I have the next error.

```
error: @InverseMethods must have a non-void return type
```

So I will be glad to here nice explanation of the whole flow. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice to see you're using the new InverseMethod available in Android Studio 3.0.

You're using two-way data binding with a method and the expression must understand how to set the value when the user modifies the text. The use is intended for conversion methods, so I don't know if this applies in your case.

Essentially, data binding uses code like this when setting the text to the View:

```
EditText edit = binding.edtPrice;
edit.setText(shipper.getPrice(priceKey));
```

And when the text changes, you are asking it to do this:

```
EditText edit = binding.edtPrice;
priceKey = shipper.setPrice(priceKey, edit.getText());
```

That's clearly not going to work and it gives you an error.

There are two things wrong, really. The first is that `getPrice()` returns an `int` instead of a `CharSequence` or `String`. The second is that `setPrice()` isn't really doing a conversion -- it takes a different number of parameters and returns a `void`.

In your case, you're not trying to convert priceKey into an integer; you're trying to access a value in a map of some sort. There are a few ways to handle this. I think the easiest way is to use a map directly in your model. Here, I'll assume that you have a final field, but you could return it as a property using getters and setters:

```
public class ShipperModel {
    public final ObservableArrayMap<Object, Integer> price = new ObservableArrayMap<>();
    //...
}
```

and then in your expression:

```
<EditText android:text="@={`` + shipper.price[priceKey]}" .../>
```

If you want custom conversions, you can do it like this:

```
@InverseMethod("convertToPrice")
public String convertFromPrice(Object key, int price) {
    //...
}

public int convertToPrice(Object key, String text) {
    //...
}
```

And then you would pass the price object in the expression:

```
<EditText android:text="@={shipper.convertFromPrice(priceKey, shipper.price)}" .../>
```

I would simplify the conversion methods to make them reusable throughout my application and just convert an integer to String and back:

```
public class Converters {
  @InverseMethod("fromPrice")
  public static final int toPrice(String text) {
      //...
  }

  public static final String fromPrice(int price) {
    //...
  }
}
```

and then the expression would be:

```
<EditText android:text="@={Converters.fromPrice(shipper.price[priceKey])}" .../>
```

Comment: >>> The first is that getPrice() returns an int instead of a CharSequence or String --- I`ve already have declined methods for these conversions,  but otherwise it`s really great and nice description! Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, it is the right answer. Since when you change the model(besides the case where the model inherit from the BaseObservable and your class fields has @Bindable annotation with corresponding calls notifyChange() inside the model) - databinding does not know about your changes. So, Observables from the android.databinding package - is the real solution. Thanks, guys for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing your own binding methods in this case, consider using an [`ObservableMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableMap.html).

```
public final ObservableMap<Object, Integer> price = new ObservableArrayMap<>();
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtPrice"
    style="@style/CreateShipperItemValueEditTextView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="@string/hint_price"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@={shipper.price[priceKey]}"/>
```

But the issue is with converting the text value (a `CharSequence`) to the mapped value (an `int`). For this you need the `@InverseMethod`. In your case such a method is not sufficient though. So you need to provide an `@InverseBindingAdapter` instead.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text", event = "android:textAttrChanged")
public static Integer convertTextToInteger(EditText view) {
    String text = view.getText().toString();
    return text.isEmpty() ? null : Integer.parseInt(text);
}
```

Also you'll have to provide a `@BindingConversion` or a `@BindingAdapter` for mapping integers to `CharSequence` to set the text in the first place.

```
@BindingConversion
public static CharSequence convertMyClass(Integer i) {
    return i == null ? null : i.toString();
}
```

Comment: I have already declined @InverseBindingAdapter. It doesn`t help. Maybe ObservableMap will be the solution. I will check this and put a comment later. Thanks.